# Modifying a regex for a better matching

Tags: java, regex, url, match

Considering we have this regex to match URLs in a page:

```
(https?):\\/\\/(www\\.)?[a-z0-9\\.:].*?(?=\\s)
```

My question is that how we can improve it to, for example, matches:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

instead of :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">home</a></div><div>
```

In short, I want it to filter any of `;:'".,<>?«»“”‘’` that usually comes after URLs in a page HTML code.

Comment: The right answer is "use an HTML parser". A possible answer: `(https?)://(www\\.)?[a-z0-9.:][^<>"]+`

Comment: Just use [the `URI` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)!

Comment: @fge do you mind for some more explanations?

Comment: @stribizhev I used and it did not work as I wanted. I used `tagsoup` to standardize the HTML code to an XML one and then formed a DOM and traversed it. But it did not work well for me. Maybe you mind to send an actual full described answer?

Comment: Simple: if you submit the string as a constructor to `URI`, it will be able to tell immediately whether the URI is valid. And once you have a valid URI object, you can query what the scheme/host/path/etc are.

Comment: Did you try `Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");` + `String absHref = link.attr("abs:href");` in a foreach with JSOUP?

Comment: @fge you probably mistook my mean. Of course the second string in my question is not valid and it will skip it. But it should take the URL out of that string. Does the `URI` do as such?

Comment: @stribizhev no i did not. I do not even know how to work with JSoup. But I guess it will still take something like the second String in my question, as the result of what you mentioned in your comment. Right?

Comment: Yes, `URI` does, since any URI is also a URL.

Comment: @fge I know that, but my question is that if the URI class you mentioned, actually extract URL from inside a string? If does, then why there are tens of different regex here or on the other places for matching URLs? Did not they think of using a URI??

Comment: Well, it's a mystery to me why they didn't use that class in the first place; it accurately decomposes a URI from a string and is more efficient at that than regexes....

Comment: @stribizhev by the way, your first comment looks working quite well!

Comment: Cool, but I'd still refrain from posting a regex-based solution for an HTML parsing task.

Comment: As my second question, is this possible to extract the part that is filtered by `[^<>"]+` as a separate Group of this regex? I mean, for example, `group(1)` gives the URL and `group(2)` gives the surrounding text within those chars?

Comment: @stribizhev I do not know why, but I prefer to use a library as less as possible in my work cause in my mind this decreases the originality of my work. While it is hard to make a HTML parser on my mind, so I turned into using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already are using JSOUP, I think the best way to get all links is using this library. It is not losing originality, it is a question of your code safety, readability and maintainability.

[Here is an example from **Jsoup Cookbook** how you can collect all links](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) from `href` and `src` attributes (basically, from your regex I see that you only want to match those):

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
for (Element src : media) {
    links.add(src.attr("abs:src"));
}
for (Element link : imports) {
    links.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
}
for (Element link : links) {
    links.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
}
```

Note that this method will let you get all absolute path links, even those that were relative.

If you do not need that and want to show off to your boss, try the following regex:

```
https?://(?:www\\.)?[a-z0-9.:][^<>"]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oN7oR5/1)

Here, `[^<>"]+` matches 1 or more symbols other than `<`, `>` and `"`. Thus, it restricts the regex not to cross the attribute boundary. You might want to add `'` there, too.

Comment: Who said I am already using JSOUP? :)
But I was wondering if you could answer the previous comment too, though so far it is really a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, I am confused with some aspect of regex. why `[a-z0-9.:]` ends of to be a part of extracted string but `[^<>"]+` makes the match to be excluded from that string?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the tagsoup and jsoup. As for the regex, I do not understand the comment above, but as for groupings, you can use [`https?://(?:www\.)?([^<>"]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oN7oR5/2) (I added `\n` at the online tester for demo only), and then you will be able to access the whole URL with `.group(0)` and the one captured with the capturing group via `.group(1)`.

Comment: I just feel confused with regex. I do not know why`[a-z0-9.:]` means `match a single character present in the list below` but `[^<>"]+` means `match a single character not present in the list below:...` is it because of `^`?  you got me wrong. I wanted `.group(1)` to be `home`. in other words, wanted it to capture the text surrounded after URL between those chars.

Comment: That is already pure HTML parsing and I really urge you to switch to an HTML parsing library. Regex will most likely cause other issues that I cannot predict looking at your HTML code now. Yes, `^` in `[^...]` is a *negation operator* meaning *all but those in the class*. To get `home` as group(1), you need [`https?://(?:www\.)?[^\n<>"]+(?:"[^<]*>([^<]*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/nR6gB6/1). Note that Group1 will not always be set, and will be `null` in those cases. Check it for null.

Comment: Yea, I know it will return null because not all those URLs in the HTML codes are followed by some words within those chars.  I will try to take your advice into consideration if some fatal errors happens.